# How to get img src inside a href jquery

Tags: jquery, html, image, href

Hi i have an image inside a href. Is there any way to get the img src as text using jQuery?

```
<a id="img_id"><img src='add-icon.png' height="15" width="15"></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var img_src = $("#img_id").find("img").attr("src");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  jquery `attr` method to retrive `img` `src`

```
 $("#img_id img").attr('src');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) to locate the `img` and then use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr) to get the `src` attribute value

```
var src = $('#img_id img').attr('src')
var src = $('#img_id > img').attr('src')
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<a id="img_id"><img src='add-icon.png' height="15" width="15" id="myimg"></a>
```

jQuery

```
$("#myimg").attr('src');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var t = $('#img_id').find('img').attr('src');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var imagesrc =  $("#img_id").find("img").attr("src");
```

reference **[attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var src=$("#img_id").find('img').prop('src');
```